# USB-Stick Detected as 2 Devices

Tags: ubuntu, usb, partitioning

When I plug in my USB Stick, Ubuntu detects 2 devices. One device containing a few Mebibytes and another one containing the rest of the storage.

This is rather annoying, because when I plugin in my USB into a dumb device like a printer, only the small device will show up.

I'm not confusing device with partition here, it actually shows up as 2 devices. When I open gparted I have 2 devices with both of them being my USB, both with 1 partition in them.

How do I turn it back into one single device?

Comment: What's the make/model of the drive? It would help address the answer. Chipset if you know it might also help.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is firmware related. All USB drives have a special controller chip between the RAW flash memory and the USB port. This chip uses a manufacturer specific code called firmware to translate USB packets to Flash data and reverse.

Manufacturers often supply utilities for USB Drive configuration ( here i refer to electronic omponents manufacturers as JMicron, STmicroelectronics etc, not to brands like Kingston, Corsair, Patriot and so on)

As a good starting point you should look here: http://www.usbdev.ru Try to look up your stick here, they have a database of Chips, Sticks, Utilities and other useful information

I know this site is in Russian, but Google Chrome helps a lot.

Comment: If it's a Sandisk U3 device, Sandisk offers a utility on their site to get rid of the fake "CD-ROM" device.

Comment: Sandisk uses Phison Controller chips in their sticks, the utility is just a cut down version of Phison MPAll (original, advanced utility).

Comment: @ultrasawblade The fake CD device is also detected, but not the extra device that I am talking about. I am assuming you meant the CD device that contains the driver or whatever it is for the USB?